# how to access refs in methods in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, reference, vuejs2, vue-component, ref

I want to access template ref in functions inside method objects. Currently, it throws undefined when accessing the refs.

My Code Below:

```html
<template>
    <ul ref="lvl1_target" style="width: 440px" class="lvl1_target milestone_asset_data">
        <li :style="{'width': getMileStonePercent(4,'lvl1_target')}" class="hybse_data">
            <span></span>
            <i></i>
            <small>$4M</small>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

And My Code in Script tag is below:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        getMileStonePercent(num, secWrp) {
            let ele = this.$refs[secWrp]
            return ele.offsetWidth + '%'
        },
    },
    created() {},
}
```

Kindly, provide solution to get the width by accessing the template reference in my function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `ref` attribute to the element you want to target.

I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do so here is a generic example instead:

```html
<template>
    <div ref="myElement"></div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        setText() {
            this.$refs.myElement.innerHTML = "Hello world"
        },
    },
}
```

[Vue `ref` documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

Comment: it throws undefined when i try to access myElement

Comment: From the docs: `$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties.`

Comment: You would need to handle this in the `mounted` callback.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
export default {
  methods: {
    this.$next(tick() => {
      setText() {
        this.$refs.myElement.innerHTML = "Hello world"
    }
  })
}}
```